# Unix signals weird behaviour. (children exiting many times)

Tags: c, unix, signals, fork

I am practicing programming with unix signals and I am new to it,
so I wrote following program: http://wklej.org/id/2253905/ , that i am compiling in following way: gcc -Wall -o signals signals.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void child_work(int l);
void create_children(int n, int l);
void parent_work(int k, int p);
int sethandler( void (*f)(int), int sigNo);
void child_handler(int sig);
void parent_handler(int sig);
void sigchld_handler(int sig);
void usage(void);

volatile sig_atomic_t last_signal = 0;

int sethandler( void (*f)(int), int sigNo)
{
    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    act.sa_handler = f;
    if (-1==sigaction(sigNo, &act, NULL))
        return -1;

    return 0;
}



void sigchld_handler(int sig) {
    pid_t pid;
    for(;;)
    {
        pid=waitpid(0, NULL, WNOHANG);
        if(pid==0) return;
        if(pid<=0)
        {
            if(errno==ECHILD)
            {
                printf("[%d] No more children parent quits.",getpid());
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }

            perror("waitpid:");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

void child_handler(int sig)
{
    printf("[%d] received signal %d\n", getpid(), sig);
    last_signal = sig;
    if(last_signal==SIGUSR1)
        if(0==kill(0,SIGUSR2))
            printf("[%d] SENDING signal %d\n", getpid(), SIGUSR2);
        else
            perror("kill:");

}

void parent_handler(int sig) {
    printf("[%d] received signal %d\n", getpid(), sig);
    last_signal = sig;
}

void child_work(int t)
{
    int s;
    srand(getpid());
    s=rand()%(t-1)+2;
    struct timespec tt, tn = {s,0};
    for(tt=tn;nanosleep(&tt,&tt);)
    if(EINTR!=errno)
        perror("nanosleep:");



    printf("[%d] dies",getpid());
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


void create_children(int n, int t)
{
    while (n-->0)
    {
        switch (fork())
        {
        case 0:
            if(sethandler(child_handler,SIGUSR1))
            {
                perror("Seting child SIGUSR1:");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if(sethandler(child_handler,SIGUSR2))
            {
                perror("Seting child SIGUSR2:");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            child_work(t);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        case -1:
            perror("Fork:");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);


        }
    }
}

void usage(void){
    fprintf(stderr,"USAGE: signals n t\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"n - number of children > 0\n");
    fprintf(stderr,"t - max lifetime of child process\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n,t;
    //int childcount;
    if(argc!=3)
    {
        usage();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    t = atoi(argv[2]);

    if (n<=0 || t<=1) {
        usage();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if(sethandler(SIG_IGN,SIGUSR1))
    {
        perror("Seting parent SIGUSR1:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(sethandler(parent_handler,SIGUSR2))
    {
        perror("Seting parent SIGUSR2:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(sethandler(sigchld_handler,SIGCHLD))
    {
        perror("Seting parent SIGCHLD:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    create_children(n, t);
    struct timespec tt, tn = {1,0};

    while(1)
    {
        for(tt=tn;nanosleep(&tt,&tt);)
        if(EINTR!=errno) perror("nanosleep:");
        if(0==kill(0,SIGUSR1))
            printf("[%d] SENDING signal %d\n", getpid(), SIGUSR1);
        else
            perror("kill:");

    }




    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and when i run it ./program 3 3 (it spawns 3 children) i get weird output like:

```
[2835] dies[2836] dies[2834] dies[2836] dies[2836] received signal 10
[2836] received signal 12
[2836] SENDING signal 12
[2835] dies
```

as you can see [2835] and [2836] die 2 times and I am just wondering why it behaves like this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: No includes? What flags did you use with compiler and linker?

Comment: keep your signal handler simple just for raising some flags; do not use printf in handler

Answer (score 1):

Using `printf()` in signal handler function leads to undefined behavior.
I was not able to reproduce your bug with my Debian 8.3 Virtual Machine. Behavior will depend on operating system.

[Check here Async-signal-safe functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Comment: just try few times, sometimes it works properly sometimes not, also i updated my question with includes and flags like u asked.

Comment: @ HackTheGibson I tried many times, I did not get the bug. Did you try after removing non async-signal-safe functions?

Comment: @ HackTheGibson Also note that `kill()` is not Async-signal-safe, and its probably more a problem. You need to set a flag instead executing kill and kill from the infinite loop.

Comment: but kill is async-signal-safe according to your link in answer

Comment: @ HackTheGibson Sorry it is, I don't know how I missed it. But `printf()` is not, or more precisely, `printf()` is not guaranted to be. Maybe it is on my system and not on yours, so please comment the single `printf()` in signal handler in your code, rebuild program and try again.

Comment: I need formatted text, so I guess i will have to do this stuff from children and parent functions instead of from inside handler. Thank you for pointing out the error, if there are other errors pls let me know :)

Comment: @ HackTheGibson I did not see other errors. Did it solve your problem? I cannot be absolutely sure as I cannot reproduce it with the same code.